# Creating web based football simulation game

Tags: browser, web, 3d-engine, 2d-engine

I am creating an online football/soccer management game. I want to implement some simple 2d (in future maybe even 3d) graphics engine. For 2d I mean, that every player would be like a circle, view from top. But I am unsure, what technology should i use? I was looking at webgl, but it is unsupported in IE so far. Also I checked HTML5 canvas, but I am not sure it is powerful enough to run this in good framerate. Main priority is that it would run on web browser and that it should be compatible with all major browsers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want 3D, WebGL is the only option. The good news is that WebGL is slated for inclusion in IE11.

If you want 2D, you have options:

- Canvas.
- SVG.
- HTML Elements.

Of these, for most gaming solutions, Canvas is the only sensible option.

But I recommend trying out some JS gaming libraries to deal with the core rendering code, rather than writing it yourself -- it'll save you a lot of time and effort. [See here for a list of possible libraries you could try](https://gist.github.com/bebraw/768272).

Comment: Thank you. Nice list of libraries. Maybe some you have tried and would recommend?

Comment: @Dove - not really; there's a lot of them and they all have their own strengths and weaknesses depending what you want to do. The only criteria I can really recommend you make sure of is (a) pick one that is still under active development, and (b) one with a licence that is compatible with how you want to distribute your code.